# Getting warning error in debug console related to clipboard data with additional permission

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have been working in a project that involves ESP32 Bluetooth and Flutter application. My app was working fine without theses warning message about a week ago, I stayed sometime out and couldn't work on it, when I came back, came across this message. The app seems to work fine, but I get this "warning" message whenever I tap or click on something. 
If I run the App in IOS simulator, it will work fine without this error, but when running on my android device, the error shows up. 
This is the message I keep getting:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on LM G710 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:00000/dasdj02D-m=/sas
W/PlatformPlugin(23531): Attempted to get clipboard data that requires additional permission(s).
W/PlatformPlugin(23531): See the exception details for which permission(s) are required, and consider adding them to your Android Manifest as described in:
W/PlatformPlugin(23531): https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview
W/PlatformPlugin(23531): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/file/147669 from pid=23531, uid=10406 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1950)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:698)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1460)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1404)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:295)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.access$700(PlatformPlugin.java:26)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin$1.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:85)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformChannel.java:141)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6854)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
W/PlatformPlugin(23531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
```

I have tried adding this to my Android Manifest, but got no success:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.project">
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible this is related to having an image in your clipboard buffer.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65388#issuecomment-738539370

I had the same problem, and as soon as I copied some text into my clipboard on my phone, the debug messages went away.

Comment: I had the same problem, this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that looks like it happens only on LG devices. [It's already fixed on Flutter engine master branch](https://github.com/flutter/engine/commit/b2ace0cccb441e320beb9701015a323e97a1b5d2) but it may take some time to land on Flutter stable.

You may want to try the `flutter clean` which *somehow* help one of the developers under the corresponding GitHub issue. If it won't help, [there's a temporary workaround](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66108#issuecomment-695218268).